# Is there any way to make the code shorter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have implemented a JavaScript code in my web site, the code runs to toggle the slide, and there are 15 such slides, so for each I have implemented slide toggle code, but I want to know is there any shorter way such that I write the code once and it gets implemented on all the slides.

```
    $(".main1").click(function(){
    $(".show1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main2").click(function(){
    $(".show2").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main3").click(function(){
    $(".show3").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main4").click(function(){
    $(".show4").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main5").click(function(){
    $(".show5").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main6").click(function(){
    $(".show6").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main7").click(function(){
    $(".show7").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main8").click(function(){
    $(".show8").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main9").click(function(){
    $(".show9").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main10").click(function(){
    $(".show10").slideToggle("slow");
});
    $(".main11").click(function(){
    $(".show11").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main12").click(function(){
    $(".show12").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main13").click(function(){
    $(".show13").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main14").click(function(){
    $(".show14").slideToggle("slow");
  });
    $(".main15").click(function(){
    $(".show15").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

Comment: Please show the HTML on which the JavaScript runs. There could be a much easier way of doing this, depending on the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will work on your end.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  $(".main" + i).click(function(){
    $(".show" + i).slideToggle("slow");
  });
}
```

Comment: It worked, but I wanna know how the code is getting interpreted, I mean the code gets evaluated to all the 15 slides, like suppose i=1 code is $(".main1").click(function(){
    $(".show1").slideToggle("slow");
  });

Comment: it worked but I wanna know how the code is getting interpreted, I mean how the code is getting evaluated to all the 15 slides, like for i=1 the code is $(".main1").click(function(){
    $(".show1").slideToggle("slow");
  }); and in next loop the code changes to i=2 $(".main2").click(function(){
    $(".show2").slideToggle("slow");
  }); so for i=i the data is not saved anywhere and the code inside for loop is changed everytime for new value of i. Please explain

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I'm not quite sure what you mean by "for i=i" ... if I assume that your question is "where are all the singular values of i inside the function stored?", then the answer is: in a closure. Basically: if you define an anonymous function in a loop, then a new function is created _at runtime_ for each run of the loop, and each of those functions keeps a memory of the variables used from the outer scope _at the time of creation_. This concept is called a "closure" and it works implicitely in JS. See the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 1):

Put the same class on every element, then use a `data` attribute to target the different instances you want to `slideToggle()`. Using this method the same three lines of JS will work for an infinite number of related elements within the HTML.

```js
$(".main").click(function() {
  $(this.dataset.target).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.show { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="main" data-target="#show-1">Show 1</a>
<a href="#" class="main" data-target="#show-2">Show 2</a>
<a href="#" class="main" data-target="#show-3">Show 3</a>

<div class="show" id="show-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="show" id="show-2">Dolor sit</div>
<div class="show" id="show-3">Amet consectetur</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Traverse the DOM solution

Use `this` keyword and [traverse the DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp)

> which means "move through", are used to "find" (or select) HTML
> elements based on their relation to other elements

That's it.

For example: If the content is the next sibling element of the button use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) (**2 lines of code**).

```js
$('button.slider_trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="slider_trigger">Toggle 1</button>
  <p class="content">
    This is the paragraph 1 to end all paragraphs.  You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life.  Congratulations!
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="slider_trigger">Toggle 2</button>
  <p class="content">
    This is the paragraph 1 to end all paragraphs.  You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life.  Congratulations!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using a for loop:

```js
for (let i=1; i<16; i++){
    $((".main"+i.toString())).click(function(){
        $((".show"+i.toString())).slideToggle("slow");
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `class` attribute of your HTML markup contains a single class, or if your `class` attribute starts with `main`, then you can use this CSS selector with jQuery:

```
$('[class^="main"]').click(function() {
    const target = $(this).attr('class').replace('main', 'show');

    $(target).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The `[class^="main"]` basically states: select all elements who's `class` attribute starts with `main`, and register event handlers for all of them.

Then, when the click occurs, we'll be replacing the string `main` with `show`, thus preserving your enumeration, i.e. on click of `main17`

```
main17: show17
```

And the callback `slideToggle` will be called upon `show17` element.

Further on, I would recommend the [solution suggested by Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64390133/4475908), because however, my solution looked elegant to you, it may have performance and functional issues.

Reference:

- [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”] - jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach, as stated in other answers here, is to use `main` and `show` classes instead of `main1`, `main2`, `main3` etc.

If for some reason you cannot improve you html structure you may use jquery with `regex` to target the elements:

```js
$("[class^=main]").click(function(Event) {
    var id = this.className.match(/main(\d+)/)[1];
    $(".show" + id).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="main1">Toggle 1</button>
<p class="show1">
  This is the paragraph 1 to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
</p>

<button class="main2">Toggle 2</button>
<p class="show2">
  This is the paragraph 2 to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
</p>
```